# Spritekit | Swift3 | Level Editor - Referencing the user data for SKSpritenodes from the Level Editor

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

In my level editor I have created a SKSpritenode with a name of "windmill".
To this I've added a user data attribute (rotation | String | left)

```
//I have no problem in loading the object in the GameScene class.
enumerateChildNodes(withName: "windmill") {windmillNode,_ in
        windmill = windmillNode as? SKSpriteNode
        windmillNode.zPosition = 3
        windmillNode.move(toParent: _gameNode)
}
```

But what I want to do is call the user data property and depending on the rotation value. I want to set the angle.

--- Error "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '_?'
Is the expression correct?

```
var angle: Int
     if (windmillNode.userData?.object(forKey: "rotation")) = "left" {
         angle = 360
     } else {
         angle = -360
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single `=` is an assignment, you want to do a comparison so use `==`. So your expression looks like

```
    let rotation = windmillNode.userData?.value(forKey: "rotation")
    if let rotation = rotation as? String {
        print(rotation == "left")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks some progress. Had to declare the any to a string for the operate to work. if String(describing: windmillNode.userData?.object(forKey: "rotation")) == "left" {}

Comment: However, the if statement does not find any SKSpritenodes with rotation value of "left", so its always -360. Is this the right way of calling the userdata of a node from the editor?

Comment: Figured it out. The "left" value in the editor is being pulled through as "Optional(left)". Did a print on the userdata and found out. No idea idea but when I == "Optional(left)", the angle was 360 instead of -360.

Comment: You could try using `value:forKey`. I updated the example.

Comment: Still returns Optional(left) after changing to value. Anyways a minor tweak to me == "string" but its working now

Comment: I updated the example to show a better way to unwrap an optional

Comment: Thanks @MarkBrownsword

Comment: Updated to properly unwrap an optional before checking its value

Answer (score 0):

```
    var angle: Int
    if String(describing: windmillNode.userData?.object(forKey: "rotation")) == "Optional(left)" {
            angle = 360  
        } else {
            angle = -360
        }
```

When you set a user data value of node in the level editor as a string.

When calling the user data value in code, the value returns in my instance as Optional(left). Unsure it returns as this and not just "left"

Changing the == "string" to match this correctly assigns the right angle.